# Old Ubuntu release for older laptop

Tags: .desktop, versions

Which is the last Ubuntu version that had a top bar, allowed multiple desktops to be created and switched with a cube effect and it had some nice desktop effects called "compiz" if I remember correctly?

I had it installed a few years ago and now I want to install it on a older laptop. I dislike the latest version.

Comment: Look at Ubuntu Mate 16.04. It's actually not old, but looks similar to Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the first version which implemented compiz and the Unity Desktop instead of the old Gnome desktop.  The first LTS Ubuntu version to implement Unity and compiz was 12.04.

It is still available for download [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/).